# Configuring nuget for visual-studio-generated docker build

Tags: .net-core, dockerfile, nuget

Visual Studio now [generates](https://aka.ms/containerfastmode) Dockerfile for dotnet projects, and we are using it (with slight tweaks) for our continuous integration.

However that Dockerfile does not have any provision for configuring nuget. It even only copies the `.csproj` file from context before running `dotnet restore` to avoid re-running that step during development.

But our project requires some modules from internal, password-protected repository, so I need to provide package sources and credentials to the `dotnet restore` command inside.

What is the best current practice for injecting a (environment-specific) nuget configuration?

Answer (score 2):

This is documented here: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/documentation/scenarios/nuget-credentials.md.

To summarize, there are a variety of ways in which this can be done:

- Use a multi-stage build to protect nuget.config that contains hard-coded credentials. Only recommended if you ensure that credentials are kept out of source code control and the nuget.config file is ephemeral.
- Passing [secrets by file with BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information). This is similar to the previous option but makes use of Dockerfile secrets to provide access to the nuget.config file.
- Use environment variables in nuget.config. In this scenario, the nuget.config file would reference environment variables for its credential values. The environment variables would then be set by the build machine when executing a `docker build`.
- Use the [Azure Artifact Credential Provider](https://github.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider). This is only possible if you make use of Azure Artifacts for your package feed.

No matter which option you choose, be sure that credentials are never stored within an image layer that is published.

Comment: The visual-studio-generated dockerfile is always multi-stage, so excluding the credentials from the final image should be taken care of. But it's not clear which of the options will actually work from visual studio container tools (that is, I suspect buildkit secrets are not (yet)).

Comment: For VS, you would let it handle your authentication to the feed. The authentication is handled separately between running from VS and building the Dockerfile from command line. VS doesn't actually build all the stages in your Dockerfile. It's actually building the project locally and then volume mounting the output into the container. (You can prove this by deleting all the stages from your Dockerfile except the base stage and it will still work in VS.) So as long as VS can authenticate to your feed, you should be good.